# A question regarding to the one-body operators in N-particle Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-space, second-quantization

Recently, I've started studying the book "condensed matter field theory" by Alexander Altland and Ben Simons. At second chapter when he's trying to rationalize the one-body operators in Fock space, I can not get it. I googled it and found out this [one](http://physics.wustl.edu/wimd/chap2.pdf). During this article we can start from equation 2.28 which it's been told that one-body operator can be written in the following form,
$$F=\sum _{ \alpha  }{ \sum _{ \beta  }{\left| \alpha \right> \left< \alpha \right| F \left| \beta \right> \left< \beta \right|  }  } $$
and then it claims that the corresponding extension of this operator in N-particle space is simply,
$$F_{N} = F(1) + F(2) + ... + F(N) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}{F(i)}  $$
which each operator $F(i)$ acts only on particle $i$. Then he applys $F(i)$ on a product state. 
$$F(i) \left| \alpha_{1}\alpha_{2} ...\alpha_{N} \right) = \left| \alpha_{1} \right> \left| \alpha_{2} \right> ... \left| \alpha_{i-1} \right> \{ \sum_{\beta_{i}}{\left| \beta_{i} \right> \left< \beta_{i} \right| F \left| \alpha_{i} \right> \} \left| \alpha_{i+1} \right> ... \left| \alpha_{N} \right> } $$
$$= \sum_{\beta_{i}}{{\left< \beta_{i} \right| F \left| \alpha_{i} \right>}} \left| \alpha_{1} ... \alpha_{i-1} \beta_{i} \alpha_{i+1} ...\alpha_{N} \right)$$
I can not understand this part that why he does believe that the two following terms are same?
$$ \left< \beta_{i} \right| F(i) \left| \alpha_{i} \right> =\left< \beta_{i} \right| F \left| \alpha_{i} \right> $$
and it says, "Note that the matrix elements of $F$ do not depend on which particle is considered".
And another question for me would be that what's the form for $F(i)$?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is - the *definition* of $F(i)$ is that it acts on the $i$-th particle states as $F$ and as the identity on the rest.

Comment: Can you show it mathematically? By using first equation.

Comment: I've been reading the same book and I can't get what they do with one-particle operators either. It seems to me that any inner product between a multiparticle state and a oneparticle state should be equal to zero, so I don't understand how do they do the trick