# Representation of one-body operator in field theory

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, many-body

Section 2.1 Introduction to second quantization, Page No 47 of [Condensed Matter Field Theory](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Condensed_Matter_Field_Theory/gk4hAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) reads

> **Representation of operator (one-body)** Single-particle or one-body operator $\mathcal{O}_1$ acting in the $N$-particle Hilbert space $\mathcal{F}^N$ generally take the form $\mathcal{O}_1=\sum_{n=1}^N\mathcal{o}_n$ where $\mathcal{o}_n$ is an ordinary single-particle operator acting on the $n$th particle. A typical example is kinetic energy operator $T=\sum_n p^2_n/2m$, where $p_n$ is the momentum operator acting on the $n$th particle.

I don't understand what they do. They *really* mean by the single-particle operator since they use the same word for $o$ and $\mathcal{O}$. I find $\mathcal{O}$ to be a many-body operator (due to some flaw in my thinking). Consider one of the example of a Total kinetic energy operator
$$T=\sum_n \frac{p^2_n}{2m}$$
This operator acts on any general state since

$$T=\frac{p_1^2}{2m} \prod_{i=2}^{N} \otimes \ I_i + I_1 \otimes \frac{p_2^2}{2m}\prod_{i=3}^N \otimes\ I_i  +\cdots $$
This operator can act on a general $N$-particle state. Can you point out the flaw here? What does the author mean by One-body or Single-particle operator $\mathcal{O}_1$?

---

There are two questions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323587/247238) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291168/247238) asked, but they don't clarify my doubt.

Comment: *Can you point out the flaw here?* -what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Indeed, $\mathcal O_1$ is a many-body operator, i.e. it acts on $N$-particle states. I guess it is called one-body operator since it is constructed from a one-body operator $o_1$, which acts on the single-particle Hilbert space only. Similarly, a many-body operator $\mathcal O_2$ can be constructed from two-particle operators $o_{ij}$ which act on the Hilbert space(s) of two particles.